# App Cloner signs applications with own certificate (key) how?

Tags: android, android-studio, security, reverse-engineering, apktool

**Hello Dear StackOverflow Users.**

The question is. I clone applications using App Cloner with parameters bypassing the check for locasia, fake android id, have it, sim inform .. and many others.

But the most important thing is that the cloned application has a google map and push notifications. When I change (smali code) apps using  Apktool google map and push notification does not work because google map works with app fingerprints. he checks! I tried to sign the attachments in many ways to match the Sha256 prints, but no, it didn't work!
The cloned app with Appcloner works fine (Google maps showing, Push working)
The signed and edited app some functions (smali coded) with apktool works. But (Google maps not showing, push not working). I tried add to manifest own Google Maps Api Token. Then Maps Working, push not working. But that doesn't change the point.

I've been looking all day for ways to sign an attachment with the same signatures. But unfortunately I did not find it. or badly looking.

**question:**
how an app cloner signs applications with the same signatures.

**here is the proof:**

[image]

Comment: "Cloning an app will change its certificate" - from App Cloner's website.  It is, of course, impossible to re-sign an app with the original certificate if you lack the private key.  Could you describe how to reproduce this?

Comment: @RyanM yes i read that too. but when I cloned the apps I was surprised. look at the screenshot you can see this.